# Finding constant $c$ such that $\pi(y) \log(y) - \pi(y/2) \log (y/2) < cy $.

Tags: number-theory

Finding constant $c$ such that $\pi(y) \log(y) - \pi(y/2) \log (y/2) < cy $.

I am in the middle of deducing an upper bound for the prime counting function. This is a middle step to smoothen the prime counting function by logarithm. What I have from previous work is $$\pi(y) - \pi(y/2) < \frac{1}{2}\log (2) \left(\frac{y}{\log y}  \right).$$

I have tried multiplying $\log y$ but it took me nowhere as one coefficient says $\log y/2$ and is pretty tricky to handle. Any thought would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying through
$$
\left(\pi(y) - \pi(y/2))\right)\log y < \frac{\log y \log 2}{2}\left(\frac{y}{\log y}  \right),
$$
expanding left hand side and clearing right hand side
$$
\pi(y)\log y - \pi(y/2) \log y < \frac{\log y \log 2}{2}\left(\frac{y}{\log y}  \right)=\frac{\log 2}{2} y,
$$
adding $\pi(y/2) \log 2$ to both sides
$$
\pi(y)\log y - \pi(y/2) \log y + \pi(y/2) \log 2 < \frac{\log 2}{2} (y+ 2 \pi(y/2)),
$$
merging LHS gives
$$
\pi(y)\log y - \pi(y/2) \log (y/2) < \frac{\log 2}{2} (y+ 2 \pi(y/2)).
$$
Now, even if all odd numbers in the interval $[2,y/2]\cap \mathbb{N}$ were odd we would have $2 \pi(y/2)\leq y$ which is a very loose upper bound but still yields your inequality with $c=\log 2.$

Comment: Oh Thanks! I thought about this and I missed the part that I can just make it pretty loose.